# align bottom and responsive design

Tags: html, css

I want to build a page with a banner at its base. if my page is big enough, my code works fine but if I reduce the width of the screen everything overlaps.
I would like that if the screen is not wide enough, that my page is displayed and that only after the banner is displayed as if it were two div one under the other. Can you help me please ?

My page is built like this

```
<div class="sp-page-home" >
    <p>the content of the page</p>
    <div style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0">the content of the banner</div>
</div>
```

my css :

```
.sp-page-home {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/home.png) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: my english is bad i used google transation.... sorry

Comment: It would help if we could run your code - can you give a link to a JSFiddle, or put your code in a snippet inside the question? It might also help if you included an image of what's happening right now versus what you want to see happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the html and body tags a height of 100%.

```css
.sp-page-home {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/home.png) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sp-page-home" >
    <p>the content of the page</p>
    <div style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0">the content of the banner</div>
</div>
```

```css
.sp-page-home {
        width: 100%;
        background: url(../img/home.png) no-repeat center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    html, body{
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="sp-page-home" >
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <p>the content of the page</p>
        <div style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0">the content of the banner</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It wasn't really clear to me how this solved the question asked - could you provide a bit more detail and explanation?

Comment: @rooky06 No problem.